# What does "normalized" mean in this datasheet?

Tags: transistors, current, dc, gain

I came across the graph below in [ONSemi's 2N3904 datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2N3903-D.PDF) that depicts the DC current gain.

I don't understand what "normalized" means. I've read other explanations by Googling, but found all of them to be more vague than helpful.  Please explain what "normalized" means in this context, and why they would use it in place of the DC gain numbers?

[image]

Comment: It would be better if you included a link to the data sheet you got the chart from. Does the data sheet happen to give a value for hFE at 8 mA collector current with VCE=1.0 V at 25 °C? If so, the chart shows that as 1, and you can work out the actual values at different temperatures and collector currents with a simple multiplication. Also, it may make it easier to compare the characteristics of different transistors.

Answer (score 4):

I think there can be a rather large variation in the gain between individual parts. A range of a 100..300 is given elsewhere in the datasheet. (page 2 in this [datasheet from ONsemi](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2N3903-D.PDF))

For a particular part, the actual gain at 10 mA/25 °C might be 120  and for another part it might be 150. The graph seems to be fixed so that the 25 °C curve is 1.0 at 10 mA, so it would appear the other values are given in relation to that point. The absolute values aren't useful here since they might be different from part to part.

In other words, whatever the gain at 10 mA/25 °C for a particular transistor, the graph tells us the gain at 1 mA should be around 0.75 times that.

(Not that this is mentioned explicitly in the datasheet, so I might be mistaken.)

Answer (score 4):

In this case, "normalized" means *"relative to the values stated elsewhere"*.  A normalized value of 1 therefore means *"the same as the value stated elsewhere"*.

In the example you show, note that 1.0 is about in the middle on the Y axis.  That Y value of 1.0 tells you that you get the gain stated elsewhere in the datasheet.  At 125 °C and 5 mA collector current, you get about 1.5 times more gain than the numbers in the table otherwise indicate.

The way the datasheet is organized, the tables give you the expected gain at a few points.  Many things effect gain of transistors.  The purpose of the graph is to give you some guidance on how the gain changes as a function of collector current and temperature, *relative to the numbers stated in the table*.

Answer (score 3):

The data sheet normally gives a clue: -

[image]

The table doesn't explicitly state that hFE is normalized at 100 to 300 (Ic = 10 mA) but this is what they actually imply.

So a normalized 1.0 can cover transistors with a range of hFEs from 100 (minimum) to 300 (maximum).

Comment: Thank you gentlemen for your replies.
So what you're saying is that at -55ºC, drawing Ic= 10mA, will give me a guaranteed 0.5 of the hFE 100~300?

Comment: @pirateman1966 OK, guarantees are a little trickier so you have to use a minimum hFE value of 100 and, at -55 degC this will typically (not guaranteed) to be at 50. The graph in your question is a typical graph as stated in the title but, if you use the worst case hFE value of 100 it aint gonna be far off, maybe 40 is a reliable figure. And also remember this is at a Vce of 1.0 volts so if you have a bigger voltage across the device then hFE is almost certainly more. Guarantees are difficult to find!